# Does Pyomo allow parallel construction of model?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I have a large-scale scenarios-based optimization model that takes a long time to solve on Pyomo using the Gurobi solver. While solving the model using Gurobi (as it uses all available cores) is quick, the constraints definition part (done by Pyomo) takes all the time. Can we parallelize the model definition part on Pyomo? I asked chatGPT, which said the model definition part is inherently done in a single process and can not be parallelized. I was just wondering if you have encountered the same problem and have a way around it.

** My understanding of solving an optimization model using Pyomo and Gurobi solver is that Pyomo defines and constructs the model and passes it to the Gurobi solver to solve it. I want to leverage a parallel computing mechanism for the model construction part (done by Pyomo). Apparently, this is not possible.

*** The following two constraints are taking the majority of the time:

```
for k in range(len(y)):
    for i in range(NumBus):
        model.Constraints.add(inequality(Pminm[i], model.P[i]-model.Lambda[i] * sum(y[k, :]), Pmaxm[i]))


for k in range(len(y)):
    for i in range(NumBus):
        for j in range(NumBus):
            if i != j:
                model.Constraints.add(
                    inequality(
                        -100, 
                        B[i, j] * (
                            model.Angles[i] + 
                            sum(B_u[i, m] * (y[k, i] - model.Lambda[m]) for m in range(NumBus)) - 
                            model.Angles[j] - 
                            sum(B_u[j, n] * (y[k, j] - model.Lambda[n]) for n in range(NumBus))
                        ),
                        100
                    )
                )
```

Here, len(y)=10,000 and NumBus=118.

Comment: Your understanding above is correct.  AFAIK, there is no way to federate the model construction process.  That said, there can be efficient/non-efficient ways to construct large constraints.  You could edit your post and include one that is suspicious.  Roughly how large is your model (variables/constraints) and what is the approx build time?

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. Total computation time looks like this: roughly 3% for data pre-processing, 90% for build time, and 7% for solving the model. Since it is a scenario-based model, I have to replicate the same constraint with different parameters many times, which takes most of the time. Since those constraints are independent, I wondered if we could utilize the parallel model construction with Pyomo.

Comment: Without a bit of data on the model size and how long it takes to build, it is tough to gage odd behavior.  As stated, you *might* be using an inefficient construct in your constraints.  If you want an opinion on that, add the code for a couple to your question.

Comment: If it is just 1 constraint that is different and you have just a couple scenarios (all guesswork) you might make several instances of the constraint and then activate/deactivate them individually.

Comment: Hi, I just added that information to the post. I have 10,000 scenarios and those two set of constraints (118*118) has to be replicated 10,000 times. So basically, will have 10k*118*118 constraints.

Comment: That is a ridiculous number of constraints--a HUGE model.  You might want to look at reformulating in some other way.

Comment: By just looking at those two constraints, do you think I can write those constraints more efficiently? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything I'd do different in the constraint itself....